# Recursive sequence with Complex numbers, missing conclusion.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, complex-numbers

I am solving the following task:

Let $a_1 = \sqrt{2}\sqrt{3}*i, a_{n+1} =\frac{i* a_n}{n+1}$

What can you say about the convergence of $a_n$?
I already found out a lot. What i concluded so far, is:

We can also write $a_n$ like this:

$$a_n = \frac{Re(n) +i*Im(n)}{n!}$$

As for the real and imaginary part we can say that

$Re(n) = \sqrt{2} - \frac{n-1}{2}$ for odd n
$Re(n) = \sqrt{3} - \frac{n}{2}$ for even n

and $Im(n) = Re(n-1), Re(n) = Im(n-1)*i$

So i think the sequence is convergent, because n! grows way faster than the numerator. But i am missing the exact conclusion, because i still lack of understanding of how to divide the fraction above, what is the result for each n ? Is it a complex number as well?

If i multiply with the numerators conjugation i get:

$$\frac{Re(n) +i*Im(n)}{n!}\frac{Re(n) -i*Im(n)}{Re(n) -i*Im(n)}= \frac{Re(n)^2 +Im(n)^2}{Re(n)*n! -n! *i*Im(n)}$$

Please help me it is just the conclusion i am missing..!! Maybe i make it way to complicated? I appreciate any hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$|a_{n+1}|=|a_n|/(n+1)$ so $|a_n|\to 0$ and $a_n\to 0$ too.

Comment: How can you conclude that? If $|a_n| \rightarrow 0$ , $a_n$ must not converge. For example, the alternating series $a_n = (-1)^n$

Comment: Also, how do you know, that $|a_n|$ does not grow as quickly as n+1? I mean sure it doesnt but it is not clear.

Comment: If $|a_n|\to 0$ then $a_n$ have to converge to $0$. It directly follows from the definition of the convergence to $0$, that is for each $\varepsilon>0$ exists $N$ such that $|a_n-0|=|a_n|<\varepsilon$ for each $n>N$.

Comment: Ok, But, how can you be sure that $|a_n| \rightarrow 0$?  It is not proven

Comment: Condition $|a_{n+1}|=|a_n|/(n+1)$ should imply $|a_n|\le |a_1|/n!$, so $|a_n|\to 0$.